# When I input -1, it's resulting in arithmetic overflow

Tags: c#, .net

When I try to input -1 and its giving me this exception unhandled - Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. What would be the perfect solution to this?

```
static void Main()
{
    int linenumber;
    string[] line;
    string array;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of lines:");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out linenumber);

    line = new string [linenumber];
    
    ...

}
```

this line is throwing the exception

```
line = new string [linenumber];
```

Comment: You can't create an array with negative length ...

Comment: Why do you need the *perfect* solution?  Worry about perfection once you have *a* solution.  Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.  What exactly are you expecting to happen if you enter -1?

Comment: Validate all inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "perfect" solution is to not let the user enter invalid line numbers.

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of lines > 0:");
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out linenumber) || linenumber < 1);

string[] lines = new string[linenumber];
```

> How would I make the program end when I enter -1

Well, that's a different requirement. But of course you can do that:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of lines > 0 (exit with -1):");
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out linenumber) || linenumber == 0 || linenumber < -1);

if(linenumber == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("===========================");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

string[] lines = new string[linenumber];
```

Comment: Even better, move the `TryParse` call to the condition on the `do/while`. Consider `while (!   int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out linenumber) || linenumber <= 0)`

Comment: How would I make the program end when I enter -1

I want it to look like this instead of continuing the program

===========================
Enter the number of lines:
-1
===========================

Comment: That's a different question. You test for <0 and return. But do that before you instantiate an array of negative length

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your help, It's working the way I expected it to.